# How to change the network module of a service?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, services

I just disconnected my Wi-Fi connection on my Raspberry Pi, because it was connected via Ethernet too. (And I only need Ethernet.) So the problem is that my services like `xrdp` or `samba` were working on the Wi-Fi connection, and I can´t connect to them anymore.

How can I change the network of a service to Ethernet instead of Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 0):

Usually all services listen all Interfaces if you didn't change their configuration. When you see in configuration that a service must listen `0.0.0.0` ip address it means to listen all Interfaces.

Additionally you can assign bonding of two Interfaces (WiFi and Ethernet) in active-backup mode. You'll have one bond0 Interface witch will be accessed via WiFi or Ethernet with one ip address.